# Equivalence of measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be two measures defined on a space $\mathcal{X}$. It is given that they are equivalent, i.e., $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \nu$. I am interested in finding necessary and sufficient conditions to conclude that there exist constants $\alpha, \beta >0$ such that $\alpha \mu(X) \leq \nu(X) \leq \beta \mu(X)$ holds for all measurable sets $X \in \mathcal{X}$.

It is clear to me that equivalence is a necessary condition but I am not sure of its sufficiency. If it is sufficient, then how can one go about finding the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$? An obvious sufficient condition is $ \alpha \leq \frac{d \nu}{d \mu} \leq \beta$, i.e., the Radon-Nikodym derivative is bounded from both above and below. However, I am not sure if this is necessary. I believe the answer is related to certain properties of the derivative but I can't figure out the best way to state it.

If it helps, you can assume that the measures are finite and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure (with $\mathcal{X}$ being a bounded set, say a unit ball).

Any references or hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Say the space is the unit interval, one measure is Lebesgue measure, the other is the square root of Lebesgue measure. What happens with $[0,\alpha]$ for $\alpha$ very small?

Comment: Clearly one of the directions will hold but the other will not even though the measures are equivalent. I think in this case the Radon Nikodym derivative is unbounded (even though I am not sure I have correctly evaluated it). So does this imply boundedness of the derivative is also necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sufficient condition is (essentially) necessary; more precisely, it is necessary and sufficient to have $\alpha \le \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \le \beta$, $\mu$-almost everywhere.

It does make things simpler to assume that $\mu,\nu$ are finite, but you can weaken this later.

Suppose we have $\alpha \mu(X) \le \nu(X) \le \beta \mu(X)$ for all measurable sets $X$.  Let $r > \beta$ and consider the measurable set $X = \{ \frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \ge r\}$.  Show that $\nu(X) \ge r \mu(X)$ and conclude that $\mu(X)=0$, so that $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} < r$ almost everywhere.  Since $r > \beta$ was arbitrary, argue that this implies $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \le \beta$ almost everywhere (note that this uses countable additivity).  Then use a similar argument to show $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \ge \alpha$ as well.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thanks a lot. Just a small question, I am not sure why countable additivity would be needed. Is it because we will have to construct a sequence $r_n > \beta$ and $\lim r_n = \beta$ and then use the convergence over that? Sorry but it has been a while since I have written such kinds of proof and my skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: @sudeep5221: Yes, that's the idea.  The argument above shows that the set $X_n = \{\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} \ge r_n\}$ has measure zero, and the set $\{\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} > \beta\}$ is the countable union of those sets.  So we use countable additivity to conclude that the latter set also has measure zero.

Comment: Perfect. Got it. Thanks a lot. :)